# Can a strong electric field cause the electrons to come out of the atoms?

Tags: electrons, electric-fields, electric-current, atomic-physics, ionization-energy

Can a strong electric field cause the electrons to come out of the atoms, is this how free electron are obtained in a discharge tube?

Comment: have you read about ionization energies?

Comment: Yeah i have.... It is the min amount of energy required to remove the valence electron. And it is usually high if the distance between the valence shell and nucleus is less

Comment: See also vacuum tube

Comment: Please tell me the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is called *field emission*. It is easiest to create by having the electric field geometry between the two electrodes be highly asymmetric, as for example having the negative electrode be a sharpened needle pointing towards a flat plate which serves as the positive electrode. You can get field emission with tens to hundreds of volts; if you don't have the asymmetry then it will take thousands to tens of thousands of volts to kick the process into operation (see my answer to your other question here).

Comment: Okay, so actually what is happening is that the high voltage is causing the electrons of negative electrode to become free electrons which are ionising the atoms of the gas, right? And this is called field emmison and this is easy to obtain when we are using asymmetrical electrodes, right?

Comment: this is it: field emission is what pulls electrons loose. the electric field then accelerates them and what follows is canned the "avalanche".